# Remove incorrect [ssis-2015] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

There is a tag [ssis-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssis-2015) which is incorrect as there is not such a thing. There is no 2015 version of SQL Server Integration Server.

How can I request this tag to be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are only 8 questions, you can probably just retag them all [ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssis). Since people in those questions seem to all be talking about SSIS for Visual Studio 2015, maybe make sure the VS tag is the right version while making those edits.

Comment: thank you, I'll do that just wanted to avoid people to keep using it

Comment: @Jayvee About 24 hours after it hits 0 uses, the tag will be removed from the cache, so it will stop being suggested for new questions. For a low-use tag, that should be enough to kill it for good.